# Symfony3.4: Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony3.4, the following error occurred while supporting automatic wiring.
When I clicked on a link, I got the following error.
Other transitions were working fine. Do you have any idea?

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Error

```
Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from 
the request information for parameter "keepRequest".
//stack trace
LogicException:
Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "keepRequest".

  at vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Request/ParamConverter/DoctrineParamConverter.php:97
  at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter->apply(object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
     (vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Request/ParamConverter/ParamConverterManager.php:92)
  at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->applyConverter(object(Request), object(ParamConverter))
     (vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Request/ParamConverter/ParamConverterManager.php:48)
  at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->apply(object(Request), array('amcService' => object(ParamConverter), 'keepRequestService' => object(ParamConverter), 'ecItemService' => object(ParamConverter), 'keepRequest' => object(ParamConverter)))
     (vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/EventListener/ParamConverterListener.php:78)
  at Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener->onKernelController(object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:115)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(FilterControllerEvent), 'kernel.controller', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:214)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:143)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.controller', object(FilterControllerEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:139)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:200)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (web/app_dev.php:37)
```

KeepRequestController.php

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/hq/keepRequest")
 */
class KeepRequestController extends BaseKeepRequestController
{
    protected $indexRoute = "app_ahi_sp_admin_hq_keeprequest_index";
    /**
     *
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/")
     * @Template("AppAhiSpAdminBundle:Hq/KeepRequest:index.html.twig")
    public function indexAction(Request $request, AmcService $amcService, KeepRequestService $keepRequestService, EcItemService $ecItemService, KeepRequest $keepRequest)
    {
        return parent::indexAction($request, $amcService, $keepRequestService, $ecItemService, $keepRequest);
    }
```

html.twig

```
  <a href="{{ path('app_ahi_sp_admin_hq_keeprequest_index') }}">
     <span>Over-the-counter fitting reservation</span><i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>
  </a>
```

BaseKeepRequestController.php

```php
class BaseKeepRequestController extends BaseController
{
    protected $indexRoute;

    /**
     * List screen display action
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AmcService $amcService
     * @param KeepRequestService $keepRequestService
     * @param EcItemService $ecItemService
     * @return array
     */
    protected function indexAction(Request $request, AmcService $amcService, KeepRequestService $keepRequestService, EcItemService $ecItemService)
    {
        // Create a search form
        $searchForm = $this->createForm(KeepRequestSearchType::class, null, array(
            "action" => $this->generateUrl($this->indexRoute),
            "login_staff" => $this->getStaff(),
        ));

        // Get search criteria
        $params = $this->getSearchParameter($searchForm, $request);
        if (!$this->getStaff()->isHq()) {
            $params['shop'] = $this->getStaff()->getShop();
        }

        $amcParams = array();
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($key, 'amcMember') === 0 && $value) {
                $amcParams[str_replace('amcMember', 'member', $key)] = $value;
            }
        }
        if ($amcParams) {
            $params['amcMember'] = $amcService->getMemberIdArray($amcParams);
        }

        // Create page nation
        $count = $keepRequestService->countKeepRequestBySearchParams($params);
        $page = $request->query->getInt('page', 1);
        $num = $request->query->getInt('num', 10);
        $pagination = new Pagination($count, $page, $num, 10);

        // Obtaining a reserve request
        $keepRequests = $keepRequestService->getKeepRequestBySearchParams(
            $keepRequest, $amcService, $ecItemService, $params,
            $pagination->getItemsPerPage(),
            $pagination->getSelectedPageOffset()
        );

        //Show screen
        return array(
            "searchForm" => $searchForm->createView(),
            "keepRequests" => $keepRequests,
            "pagination" => $pagination,
        );
    }
```

KeepRequestService.php

```php
    /**
     * Registration
     *
     * @param KeepRequest $keepRequest Layaway request
     * @param \App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Service\MailService $mailService
     * @param Mail $mail
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Service\AmcService $amcService
     * @param \App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Service\EcItemService $ecItemService
     * @param Environment $twig
     */
    public function save(KeepRequest $keepRequest, MailService $mailService, Mail $mail, LoggerInterface $logger, AmcService $amcService, EcItemService $ecItemService, Environment $twig, $comment = null, $resend = false, $remind = false)
    {
        // Acquire product information and AMC member member information
        $this->getExtraData($keepRequest, $amcService, $ecItemService);

        // Set a reserve period when inventory is secured
        if ($keepRequest->getStatus() == 'keeping' && !$keepRequest->getKeepStartDate()) {
            list($keepStartDate, $keepEndDate) = $this->getKeepStartEndDate();
            $keepRequest->setKeepStartDate($keepStartDate);
            $keepRequest->setKeepEndDate($keepEndDate);
        }

        // Get the status before change from the last history
        $oldStatus = null;
        if (count($keepRequest->getHistories()) > 0) {
            $oldStatus = $keepRequest->getHistories()->last()->getStatus();
        }

        // Add history
        $keepRequest->addHistory($this->createHistory($keepRequest, $comment));

        // Reserve request registration/change
        $this->entityManager->transactional(function ($em) use ($keepRequest) {
            if ($keepRequest->getId()) {
                $this->entityManager->merge($keepRequest);
            } else {
                // Generate a reception number from id at the time of new registration
                $this->entityManager->persist($keepRequest);
                $this->entityManager->flush();
                $requestNo = sprintf("%4s%08d", date_format($keepRequest->getRequestedAt(), 'ym'), $keepRequest->getId());
                $keepRequest->setRequestNo($requestNo);
            }
        });
        ...
```

routing.yml

```yaml
app_ahi_sp_admin:
  resource: '@AppAhiSpAdminBundle/Controller/'
  type: annotation
  prefix: /admin/
  schemes: [ http ]
```

KeepRequest.php (Entity)

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Repository\KeepRequestRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="keep_request")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class KeepRequest
{
 //
}
```

KeepRequestRepository.php

```php
    /**
     * Get articles that match the inspection conditions
     * @param array $params
     * @param null $limit
     * @param null $offset
     * @return array
     */
    public function getKeepRequestBySearchParams(array $params, $limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        if (isset($params['amcMember']) && empty($params['amcMember'])) {
            return array();
        }

        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder("h")
            ->select("h")
            ->orderBy("h.requestedAt", "desc");

        if ($limit !== null) {
            $queryBuilder->setMaxResults($limit);
        }

        if ($offset !== null) {
            $queryBuilder->setFirstResult($offset);
        }

        $this->addSearchParams($queryBuilder, $params);

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

**Tried Code**
The following code has been added to Controller, BaseController, and Service.

```php
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

     * @ParamConverter("keepRequest", class="AppAhiSpCommonBundle:KeepRequest")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request, AmcService $amcService, KeepRequestService $keepRequestService, EcItemService $ecItemService, KeepRequest $keepRequest)
    {
```

Comment: What's in the KeepRequest ? I think it's in the `ParamConverter`. Is the `KeepRequest` a service ?

Comment: @jona303 Thank you for your comment.
```KeepRequest``` is an Entity.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to debug the problem? If your controller expects to receive any entity, where should it come from if your route does not contain any ID?

Comment: @NicoHaase Please confirm that Service and parent controller method have been added. The ID will be specified by ```@Route("/hq/keepRequest ")```.

Comment: Please share more details - where can I find the route definition that contains the ID to be used?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm not used to it, so I don't know exactly what information you want. Added routing.yml. Is this alright? Regarding the ID, if it points to the ID obtained by service, this time the target is a list page, so you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: Still, I have no clue where your entity should be loaded from. If `KeepRequest` is an entity, then your route **must** contain the ID of that entity such that the `ParamConverter` can load that entity from the database - just as jona303 already told you in the answer

Comment: @NicoHaase I may have finally understood it. Do you need ```@ParamConverter```? I added it to the question, but I added ```@ParamComverter```, but there was no change. Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score -1):

Ok That's a `ParamConverter` issue. You have a `Route` with 0 parameters `@Route("/")`. This route is assigned to a method that ask for an Entity in it's arguments `KeepRequest`.
The Param converted is the service that found the entities to give to the route methods. It needs a parameter to know exactly which entity to provide.

`@Route("/{id}")` the ParamConverter understands that it must search a `KeepRequest` by it's id and with the value provided in the route parameter. You can do it with all `KeepRequest` properties but I suggest you to use the unique onces.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
All the code enclosed in `is at the end of the sentence, so please consider fixing it. I think it's more understandable.
Is it better to use @ParamConverter? It seems to be supported by symfony 5 and above.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this better. By adding a entity arg in your method, you actually use the ParamConverter. It's like you asking symfony to give you an entity and symfony answers back yelling I don't know wich one I have to give you. So add a parameter in your route like `@Route("/{id}")` or remove the Entity of the arguments list of the method.

Comment: Oops. It just collapsed due to the influence of the browser. It looks pretty now. Since the relevant part is the article list screen, id is not required. I feel that parameter is passed by ```@Route("/hq/keepRequest")```. Or can it be a problem that Entity has been turned into a service?

Comment: remove your KeepRequest arg.

Comment: When I deleted KeepRequest, I got the error ```Notice: Undefined variable: keepRequest```. Service and BaseKeepRequestController.php has been added($keepRequest was originally there), so please check it as well.

Comment: You have to create it yourself. How do you imgine symfony will guess which KeepRequest you want in your controller ?

Comment: I see. I tried ParamConverter, but it didn't change. I added the code I tried to the question. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. Your asking for an Object of type `KeepRequest` that is stored in your database. Symfony understands you want an Object of that type, but has now way to know which one to give you. He needs an id or other property to filter lines of your database to select the one you need.

Comment: I see. You should add the designation, right? Looking at the Repository, it seems that "h" is selected. Is there a way to teach this to paramConverter? I could only find out how to specify the id in option. Just in case, I added Entity and Repository to the question.